# Скрытие меню от пользователей других стран

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте.

Цель: скрыть меню от других стран, для этого использовал апи яндекс карты, типа:

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
      var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
      if(geolocation.country!=='Россия'){ 
         //скрыть меню 
      }
    });
```

Хочу убедиться, работает ли этот вариант, если есть другие варианты, буду очень благодарен.

Вот сайт http://www.status-ekb.ru/ (не реклама).
Спасибо всем заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй анонимайзер или Tor браузер.

Скрин: http://s017.radikal.ru/i423/1411/c0/ee46e0abe22c.png

Comment: @xfloooo, спасибо! Работает вроде)